# Android Development: Save to an ArrayList from onResponse method

Tags: android, json

How might I be able to save the values I get from parseJSON in the list imageURLS? I tried using a setter but it did not work. The line "Log.d("here", this.imageUrls.toString()) gives me 0 even though I verified I parsed the data correctly. I would really appreciate the help! Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageView;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
    private OkHttpClient client;
    public ArrayList<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    client = new OkHttpClient();

    ArrayList imageUrlList;
    imageUrlList = prepareData();
    DataAdapter dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), imageUrlList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

}

private void setUrlList(ArrayList<String> URLS){
    this.imageUrls = URLS;
}

public ArrayList prepareData() {
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://34.72.6.126/loadimages/").build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException { parseJSON(response); }});

    Log.d("here", this.imageUrls.toString());
    ArrayList imageUrlList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < imageUrls.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("here1",imageUrls.get(i));
        ImageUrl imageUrl = new ImageUrl();
        imageUrl.setImageUrl(imageUrls.get(i));
        imageUrlList.add(imageUrl);
    }
    return imageUrlList;
}


public void parseJSON(Response response) throws IOException {
    String json = response.body().string();
    try {
        JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray dataList = Jobject.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int i = 0; i < dataList.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = dataList.getJSONObject(i);
            String e = object.getString("uncompressed_url");
            imageUrls.add(e);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setUrlList(imageUrls);
}
}
```

Comment: Your call is Asynchronous, which means `Log.d("here", this.imageUrls.toString());` executes before `public void onResponse` is called.

Comment: @VenomVendor How can I reorder it in the correct order? Should I separate the methods? Thanks!

Comment: No, I would suggest you to watch few tutorials on Async in Java or get some help from fellow programmers. It is bit hard to explain here.,